# How to delete a file after using move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php, dropbox, delete-file

Ok, I first uploaded a file using `move_uploaded_file()`. I then used Dropbox to grab that file and used Dropbox SDK to upload the file to my Dropbox account. I now don't need that file in my File Directory. I only need that file in my Dropbox account. How do I now delete this file with PHP?

My guess would be something like this: `delete_file($movie_tmp, $movie_destination);`

Thanks!

Comment: see [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just `unlink('page.html');`

Comment: @Andy Thanks for editing... I'm a new programmer and insulting isn't any way I'm going to learn anything. Any I allowed to give the best answer to Andy?